# Is there any solution with PURE CSS to solve these two camera layouts with 16/9 aspect ratio and always centered?

Tags: html, css, video, flexbox, grid

So I would like to know how far I could go with CSS grid or flex layout to solve this issue.
Here is the two camera layouts I would like to build with HTML/CSS:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note that I uploaded two versions of each layouts to demonstrate that I want them to center always, so the "black part" should be always around the videos.**
Hope you understand what I mean.

Other important thing is **I want to place contents and cover divs above the videos**, so I have to control absolute contents relative to the videos 0,0 coordinates. (Like in the pictures the "Video Title" label.) Also the **layout should follow the 16/9 aspect ratio when browser is resized** in any directions.
Last thing that in the product where I want to integrate this, there are header, panels, footer, so this layout is not the only thing on the page. (So the video container's height is not 100vh.) Maybe this is important.

**So is it possible with only HTML/CSS? Without calculating the exact size of the videos?**

For the basics I've created a jsfiddle for the 3x3 layout. I am not sure how I should create the 6-videos version. Maybe grid could do row and colspan?

https://jsfiddle.net/5s9wkoea/
→ edited w/ extras:
[https://jsfiddle.net/jnxvd52y/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/5s9wkoea/)

```css
html, body {
  background: #1f2227;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.videoContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 2px;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.video {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 0;
  position: relative;

}

.video .overlayContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.video video {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoContainer">
  <div class="video">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="overlayContent">
        <h3>Video Title</h3>
      </div>
      <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="video">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="overlayContent">
        <h3>Video Title</h3>
      </div>
      <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="video">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="overlayContent">
        <h3>Video Title</h3>
      </div>
      <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="video">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="overlayContent">
        <h3>Video Title</h3>
      </div>
      <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="video">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="overlayContent">
        <h3>Video Title</h3>
      </div>
      <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="video">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="overlayContent">
        <h3>Video Title</h3>
      </div>
      <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="video">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="overlayContent">
        <h3>Video Title</h3>
      </div>
      <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="video">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="overlayContent">
        <h3>Video Title</h3>
      </div>
      <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="video">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="overlayContent">
        <h3>Video Title</h3>
      </div>
      <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I know it's not a good answer but you can use **table**

Comment: @MohsenNewtoa if you know that it is not a good answer then why mention it in the first place? No videos are not tabular data. Thats what you have CSS-Grid for. alternativly can be done with grid aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We need a container for the videos and apply `aspect-ratio: 16/9;` to it.
2. Then we add `display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)` to the container to place the videos ina grid-layout with 3 columns.
3. To make sure that the video not mess up the grid, we apply a `width: 100% aspect-ratio: 16/9;` to the videos.
4. to make the top left video twice the size, we use the `video:first-of-type` selector to select the first video. Then we apply `grid-column: span 2; grid-row: span 2;` to it.
5. to center the video in the screen we use `flexbox` we can center along the main-axis (per default: horizontally): `justify-content: center;`. To center along the side-axis we can use: `align-items: center;`. Note that it requires a `min-height: 100vh;` to the body to make sure it spans the entire screen.
6. To make sure that the container always fit the screen, we use `media queries` and either apply a fixed height or a fixed width depending on the screen aspect-ratio.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.video-container {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

@media only screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-container {
    height: 95vh;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .video-container {
    width: 95vw;
  }
}
  

video {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}

video:first-of-type {
  grid-row: span 2;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <video controls>
    <source src="https://www.tacoshy.de/stackoverflow/testvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <video controls>
    <source src="https://www.tacoshy.de/stackoverflow/testvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <video controls>
    <source src="https://www.tacoshy.de/stackoverflow/testvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <video controls>
    <source src="https://www.tacoshy.de/stackoverflow/testvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <video controls>
    <source src="https://www.tacoshy.de/stackoverflow/testvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <video controls>
    <source src="https://www.tacoshy.de/stackoverflow/testvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: First thank you for your work. This is almost what I need.
Notes: Can you extend the solution to place contents above the video? (Like I did with Video Title label.) Other thing is you write 95vh for the height. I mentioned that there are a header and footer around the videos container. Should I extract these with calc?

Comment: you need to wrap the video-container then and apply the height/width to the wrapper that contains the video-container and text. Depending on how large the content is, a JS solution might be more practicable. Alternativly if you want to take your images as result you can use `position: absolute/relative` to do this.

Comment: I created a new jsfiddle with my extra content. Should your solution work as well? Please take a look, thank you. very much.
https://jsfiddle.net/jnxvd52y/

Comment: I think I could do it with the help of your code, so I am going to accept it, thank you!
Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/x7638ozv/1/

Comment: The only problem that sometimes the video-container overlaps the right panel, maybe if anyone can take a look at it, it would be helpful. Jsfiddle link in the previous comment. Thx.

Comment: Oh maybe I see.. The media query doesn't count with the panel, since it checks the page for the aspect ratio.

Comment: Allright I did it, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/x7638ozv/4/